# grails tomcat 7 invocation target exception

Tags: java, grails, tomcat7

We have a Grails app running in tomcat 7, was working fine till last week.
We don't know what changed.

we are getting a error as

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails.plugin.databasemigration.GrailsChangeLogParser
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvoca
```

We tried,

1. Cleaning the war building environment
2. Run dbm-update
3. Re-install tomcat
4. Increasing xms and xmx of tomcat

any thing did not help, still error is thrown 
gails version is 2.1.0

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236340/grails-2-1-1-database-migrations-error-on-deploy-tomcat-7). Follow @James comments to see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, we have done both steps from @James comment, still did not help

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was we had a server with 8GB RAM machine, till last week the war size was 58 to 59 mb. This week we released code with a new plugin google-visualization:0.6.2 (for charts) and war size became 60 mb. Our server was not capable of handling this size war.

We also verified it by placing the same war in another server with 32GB RAM and was working fine. Also if we remove google-visualization:0.6.2 (for charts) plugin and deployed in 8GB server it was working fine.